# Slider and radio button styling in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I'm trying to style some wpf user controls to make them look the same i have in my web application. I found some really great example for every control i need except for sliders and radio buttons.
Here is how they should look like:
Slider:
[image: custom slider]

Radio Button:
[image: custom radio button]

I know i should create some ControlTemplate but i don't really know where to start...
If you can provide a complete example it would be perfect, but i guess that even some good deep advise would fit my needs.
Thank you 1000!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have style sample [here](http://db.tt/7S4tRE1I). It renders this:

[image]

Comment: The answer is not useful with a broken link - would be much better with the code posted here

Answer (score 3):

I would start with [Control Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx) on MSDN pages. There are examples for most controls which give a good overview of how the control template works. Also you can extract/download the original control template and try to make your changes to it. [Download default control templates](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7812)

P.S. Actually the slider example on the first link resembles the one you describe.

Comment: I already looked at it. I find it very confusing as you have tons of code to look at just to find the little piece you are searching. Anyway, your answer is incomplete as you didn't mention the radio button styling which is kind of obscure even in msdn article you linked.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Expression Blend.

- [Learn Expression](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc197141)

and specifically this video: [Creating ControlTemplates](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc263912).

Expression Blend is something like a XAML design application - you can size, colour, adjust fill and stroke etc on all the elements in a control. It takes a little while to get used to, but you will be able to design controls with a graphical UI and Expression will provide you with the appropriate XAML to use in your project.

Comment: I tried but as my project is REALLY big (>2000 classes, > 300 user controls), expression blend keeps giving me weird errors. I wasn't able to open it, even if trying with a stupid simple project worked.

Comment: You should break your project up into more manageable pieces because that's too big. But you don't need to open your project in order to use Expression - just create a new file and use that, and cut/paste the generated XAML back into your project.